# Enabling querystrings in Code Igniter project

Tags: codeigniter, tracking

I recently launched CodeIgniter based website for someone who wishes to be advertised and linked to by affiliates, in E-newsletters and the like. This type of linking generally attaches tracking code on the end, in the form of querystrings for analytics.

`blah.com/?utm_source=MailingList&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Blah+OCt+II`

Of course if you hit that, Code Igniter displays an error about disallowed characters in the URL.

It seems that I can get around this by setting this in the config.php:

`$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";`

This at least stops the error from being displayed. I only need it to be enabled for the homepage so I read online that you can set this in the controller of choice:

`parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);`

I'm assuming that will then let the vars be parsed so the analytics JS code will pick up on it.

Does that all seem safe and logical?

Comment: Are you using CI 2.0.3? A quick test without any changes to the config allows me to add UTM codes the query string without any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest version of CodeIgniter, 2.1 has no problems with $_GET at all and 2.0.x should have been fine too.